# Promoting items on Adaptive Search not working Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I'm using **Hybris 1905**, in my project I have 3 indexes, each fo them with its own indexed type and product catalog, one of them is old (has existed since the beginning of the project) and the other 2 are kind of new, we already created an **AsCategoryAwareSearchProfile** and **AsSearchProfileActivationSet** for each of the indexes, when accessing Adaptive Search FACETS overriding is working well, but **BOOSTS is not working** well for the 2 new indexes (**it works perfectly for old index**), so not sure what config I may be missing for these...

This is what it looks like when promoting and item using **old index**(as expected):
[image]

And this si what it looks like when promoting and item using one of **new indexes**(**score** is apparently **not being updated**):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

​The issue was the main SolrSort (usually called "relevance") needed to set the "Use Boost" flag to true (it was false)

[image]